# Regex positive lookbehind at beginning doesn't work?

Tags: regex

This regex:

```
^(?<=key)match
```

can't match:

```
keymatch (at the beginning)
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` anchors to the beginning of the string, but in your pattern, you're looking behind for `key` right after matching the beginning of the string. This situation is impossible; the beginning of the string won't be preceeded by any characters.

Put `^` inside the lookbehind instead:

```
(?<=^key)match
```

https://regex101.com/r/mgV9C8/1

Comment: Out of curiosity reasons, @jw_, why not just `^keymatch`?

Comment: @JvdV the thing to capture is "match", in that way key need to be removed and length of key get subtracted to get the match index which is kind of code bloating